# Set default ASP.NET Core website name

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis-express, applicationhost

When you first run an ASP.NET Core website, Visual Studio adds an entry to `.vs\config\applicationhost.config`. It sets the site name to the name of the project. For example:

```xml
<site name="MyWebProject" id="2">
```

I wish it used the assembly name rather than the project name. In any case, how do you override it to use a name of your choosing?

Comment: Anyway that config file is for debugging. Why do you think it matters?

Comment: The IIS Express management page that you can open from the system tray uses this name to show the website it is running. You can run websites from different solutions whose project names are unique within their solutions but ambiguous across solutions.

Comment: Does changing the name in that config file work…?

Comment: @poke No. If you do that, the website doesn’t load.